# Should we move to a database from XML files?

Tags: xml, database, architecture, full-text-search

We have an application that persists to XML files. Apart from one large XML file (which acts like an index into other files), all other files are stored in separate folders and are very small (they mostly contain meta data about a document (i.e. video/pdf etc)).

From a relational point of view, there are not too many relationships between data/objects apart from meta data associated to a document that is physically stored on disk (i.e. via a directory path). So all the data is associated to documents.

Apart from searching the XML index file, all other searching is done via using the "Windows index searching".

Although the system is for a single user in the future it will be changed to multiple users which means that the index file will have several users updating it concurrently. This file may become very large (10,000+ entries where each entry contains some meta data and a reference to the document on disk)

Another requirement is to have more than one index file on different machines each managing their own document repository. Now this means that to search/browse for content we have to search across multiple machines.

With ALL this in mind, I see that having a database may resolve some of the issues but there is a lot of work to get to the stage where we have to address the issues (i.e. create an ORM model, database, repositories, commands etc).

My question or questions are can some of these issues be resolved by other ways without going via the database route?

TIA
JD

Comment: Everything can be solved in many many ways. However, in my experience, XML is rarely a good format for a database, especially if non-sequential access is required; what you'll eventually end up with is an in-memory only database with a serialization format; all functionality will be your own to write. I suggest using sqlite, mysql, mongodb, couchdb...

Comment: You mentioned mongodb/couchdb. Would the be a better fit for my domain model which seems to be pretty much meta data associated with some type of document?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a native XML database to speed up your XML handling. I've used both [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-083851.html) (embedded, library) and [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) (networked, client-server, REST) with some success. In particular, the former solved the problem of replacing lots of small XML files scattered everywhere by a single, indexed file, so it might replace your XML index file. The latter has full-text search via [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/).

Comment: Thanks for the information. How would concurrency be resolved by XML Databases?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am in the .net world so would both XML databases and tools work?

Comment: @JD: I think Berkeley DB XML has support for locking. As for .NET, I wouldn't know, but BDBXML is written in C++ (so you might wrap it in C++/CLI and C# code) while eXist can be queried using a REST interface.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if your workload is definitely moving in a direction that needs a database. Since the data is all XML already, moving to a native XML database should be the least disruptive route. The popular products these days tend to be MarkLogic if you can afford it and eXist if you can't. (I don't have an interest in either but know contented users of both.)

Comment: For the size of data described, MarkLogic's "Express" license, which is free, would probably suffice.